# React clear LocalStorage and Asyncstorage in one Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

is it possible to clear the LocalStorage and AsyncStorage in one Component?
I want to clear the Storage if the 401 error displayed.

Need to share this for React and React-Native, is there a way to solve it?
I guess with try and catch will not work.
Hope someone can help me to fix this.

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

async function clearMobile(){
  await AsyncStorage.clear();
}

const clearWeb = () => {
  localStorage.clear();
}

export const authFetch = (originalFetch => {
  return (...args) => {
    const result = originalFetch.apply(this, args);
    return result.then(
      (response) => {
        if (!response.ok && response.status === 401) 
          try {
          clearMobile();
        }
        catch {
          clearWeb();
        }
        finally {
          window.location.reload();
        }
        return response;
      }
    );
  };
})(fetch);


export default authFetch;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to clear both at the same time, both functions must be used inside the try block. [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```
    try {
      clearMobile();
      clearWeb();
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

In this way, you will have cleaned both of them. And if there is a bug, you will debug it.

I'm sorry if the question is not what I understood.